# Notification about azure blob object changes

Tags: file-upload, azure, azure-blob-storage

Can I somehow subscribe for notifications about Azure's blob object changes?

My purpose is to delegate file uploads to the client using SAS and lately (after upload is complete) update the database. It looks like I need to continuously check blob's state, but it is quite resource consuming process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now do this using [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob)

1. Create a blob trigger by specifying your storage account connection
   string and your container/{name}
2. In outputs, select the place where
   you want your notification to go to

Comment: This currently has a limitation where Newtonsoft.json has to be 9.0.1 and if you have any nugget/assembly which requires newtonsoft to be > 9.0.1 then you are out of luck.

Comment: @loneshark99 that was something I didnt notice till you mentioned it. Is there an official doc on the same?

Answer (score 11):

You can't be *notified* by the Blob Storage about a change made to a blob, but as you point out, you can *monitor* it, requesting the *ETag* on a scheduled basis to see if it's done.

That being said, the cost to monitor a blob (or even a whole container) can be close to negligible if correctly implemented. Pinging the Blob Storage once per second costs you roughly $2.5 / month. Then, by using some heuristic you can probably lower this cost to $0.25 (one check per 10s on average). At this point, it's not really interesting to try to optimize more.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to consider is to have the client notify you when it's done uploading.

Answer (score 3):

I created a file change monitor for monitoring blobs - full details at http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/monitoring-files-in-azure-blob-storage